# Are the 'beautiful things' of life, the 'beautiful' of life?

Tags: word-usage

The following question set me thinking:

[Can we use all "nouns" as adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165878/can-we-use-all-nouns-as-adjective)

What about the opposite? Can adjectives be used as nouns? What are the rules or the stylistic limits to their usage in this context?

Comment: I'll stick to a 'comment' as I'm sure this has been (at least in part) addressed here before. Adjectives rebranded as nouns are called **nominal adjectives** and are discussed in [this article](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/nominal.htm) at The Internet Grammar of English. Though many nominal adjectives are in use, this does not mean that using _any_ adjective this way is guaranteed to be acceptable.

Comment: There is a different type of conversion, far less common, resulting in a noun not taking the definite article. From the internet: 'Even there, though, nuclear is fading as an energy option. While China ...'

Comment: English has no rule limiting the ability to noun any random adjective.  It also has no rule requiring the listener will be able to understand what you are talking about.  So likely you can do what you like in this regard, but don't expect comprehension on the other end.

Comment: I think you should ask the general question in the question title and mention the example in the question body. Though this question is 30 days old already :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like:

**The Young and the Restless.**

Here it is an assumed reference to people.

Comment: I suppose alternately you could call this the elision of the noun "People" rather than converting a adjective to a noun.

Comment: @Oldcat What would you call something that **serves** as a noun.  For example:    "That government agency serves the elderly."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are hard and fast rules but, as pointed out above, comprehensibility is a problem.

It is, however, mediated by context.  Note the following:

- *The undiscovered* is always a great lure for budding scientific minds.
- *The undiscovered* never get a fair shake in Hollywood.

The first obviously refers to objects, phenomena, etc., while the second refers to people.